# libwxgtk3.0-dev package not found

Tags: package-management

I have Ubuntu 12.04, and when I try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libwxgtk3.0-dev
```

I get a message saying package not found.

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And then tried installing the package, but still got the "package not found" message.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's true. That package was added to Ubuntu after 12.04. It's in 14.04 and newer releases of Ubuntu. Ubuntu is a *snapshot distro* - 12.04 (mostly) contains a snapshot of software available in late 2011, with security patches. If you want newer software, consider upgrading to a newer release of Ubuntu.